# PDO echo result which i safed in an array

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a little problem with my code. This code is from Joe Meyer who helped me.

**My tables**

```
stundenplan
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+---------+------+
| id | user_id | tag   | stunde | fach    | lehrer  | raum |
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+---------+------+
|  1 |       1 |     1 |      1 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  2 |       1 |     1 |      2 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  3 |       1 |     1 |      3 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  4 |       1 |     1 |      4 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  5 |       1 |     1 |      5 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  6 |       1 |     1 |      6 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  7 |       1 |     2 |      1 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  8 |       1 |     2 |      2 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
| .. |     ... |   ... |    ... |     ... |     ... |  ... |

users
+---------+----------+----
| user_id | username | ...
+---------+----------+----
|       1 | User1    | ...
+---------+----------+----
```

**PHP code**

```
//Vars
$user_id = htmlentities($_SESSION["user_id"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$tage = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$stunden = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);

//SQL
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT tag, stunde, fach, lehrer, raum 
FROM stundenplan 
    INNER JOIN users ON stundenplan.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE users.user_id = :user_id
ORDER BY stundenplan.stunde, stundenplan.tag");
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();

$record = array();
$record['stunde'] = 0;
$record['tag'] = 0;

echo'
<table class="table_standard">
    <tr>
        <th class="th_titlebar" style="white-space:nowrap">Std.</th>
        <th class="th_titlebar"><center>Mo</center></th>
        <th class="th_titlebar"><center>Di</center></th>
        <th class="th_titlebar"><center>Mi</center></th>
        <th class="th_titlebar"><center>Do</center></th>
        <th class="th_titlebar"><center>Fr</center></th>
    </tr>
';
foreach ($stunden as $stunde) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="middle" class="td_contentbar" style="white-space:nowrap">'.$stunde.'</td>';
    foreach ($tage as $tag) {                
        if($stunde > $record['stunde'] || ($tag > $record['tag'] && $stunde <= $record['stunde'])) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $record = $row;
            }
        } 

        echo '<td align="middle" class="td_contentbar">';
        if($stunde == $record['stunde'] && $tag == $record['tag']) {
            echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" id="fach_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '" value="' . $record['fach'] . '">';
            echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" id="lehrer_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '" value="' . $record['lehrer'] . '">';
            echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" id="raum_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '" value="' . $record['raum'] . '">';
        } else {
            echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" placeholder="Fach" id="fach_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '">';
            echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" placeholder="Lehrer" id="lehrer_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '">';
            echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" placeholder="Raum" id="raum_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '">';
        }

        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
```

**Output**

I want to get all data from the database in each html input. But with this code I have the problem that it just takes the last result of the sql and puts it into the appropriate inputfield.

In the following pictures all fields should be filled if there is data in the database but with my code just the last sql result is output.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help me. How should I edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the Block

```
    echo '<td align="middle" class="td_contentbar">';
    if($stunde == $record['stunde'] && $tag == $record['tag']) {
        echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" id="fach_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '" value="' . $record['fach'] . '">';
        echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" id="lehrer_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '" value="' . $record['lehrer'] . '">';
        echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" id="raum_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '" value="' . $record['raum'] . '">';
    } else {
        echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" placeholder="Fach" id="fach_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '">';
        echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" placeholder="Lehrer" id="lehrer_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '">';
        echo '<input class="inputfeld sp_input" placeholder="Raum" id="raum_' . $tag . '_' . $stunde . '">';
    }

    echo '</td>';
```

needs to go into the while loop.

Comment: When I add this to the while loop the html table looks weird but I get the first sql result.